# Check if multi index is in two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, isin

I have two dataframes with columns  of state and regionname, and I'm trying to see if df2 is in df1, and add that column to df3

```
df1=
+--------------+------------+------+
|    State     | RegionName | Data |
+--------------+------------+------+
| New York     | New York   | 123  |
| Jacksonville | Florida    | ABC  |
+--------------+------------+------+
df2=
+--------------+------------+------+
|    State     | RegionName | Data |
+--------------+------------+------+
| New York     | New York   | 456  |
+--------------+------------+------+

Output would be df3=
+--------------+------------+------+-------+
|    State     | RegionName | Data | IsIn2 |
+--------------+------------+------+-------+
| New York     | New York   | 123  |     1 |
| Jacksonville | Florida    | ABC  |     0 |
+--------------+------------+------+-------+
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

Let us do

```
df1['IsIn2']=df1[['State','RegionName']].apply(tuple, axis=1).\
                  isin(df2[['State','RegionName']].apply(tuple, axis=1)).\
                  astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

[`DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html)

```
cols=['State', 'RegionName']
df1['IsIn2'] = df1[cols].stack().isin(df2[cols].stack()).all(level=0).astype(int)
print(df1)
```

**Method 2**

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with **`indicator`** and then replace `both` by 1 and other by 0 using [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and [`Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df3 = (df1.merge(df2[cols],on=cols, how='left',indicator='IsIn2')
          .assign(IsIn2=lambda x: x['IsIn2'].eq('both').astype(int)))
print(df3)
```

---

**Output**

```
          State RegionName Data  IsIn2
0      New York   New York  123      1
1  Jacksonville    Florida  ABC      0
```